# how to get random nubmer +1 or -1 (just need it for "+" or "-")

Tags: objective-c-2.0

i need random number but only +1 or -1 (to have force direction defined in box2d) how to get this only two random numbers? thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
int random = arc4rand()%2 ? -1 : 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int result = (WhateverRandomNumbersComeFromInObjectiveC() >= 0.5) ? 1 : -1;
```

Comment: don't you just love those long Objective-C method names?

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
(arc4random() % 2) * 2 - 1
```

- arc4random() gives a random integer
- (arc4random() % 2) makes it be 0 or 1
- (arc4random() % 2) * 2 makes it be 0 or 2
- (arc4random() % 2) * 2 - 1 gives you -1 or 1